# Call to undefined method Google_Client in Google Analytics while using HelloAnalyticsApi

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api

I am using Core reporting API for reporting. I have installed Google PHP API client master on my localhost server and made a file HelloAnalyticsAPi.php in src folder Where I include

> Google/Client.php
>    , 
>   Google/Service/Analytics.php

files. And use the below details

```
$client->setClientId('XXXXXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com'); 
$client->setClientSecret('XXXXXXXXXXX'); 
$client->setRedirectUri('http://localhost/analytics/src/HelloAnalyticsApi.php'); 
$client->setDeveloperKey('XXXXXXXXXXX'); 
$client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'));
$client->setUseObjects(true);
```

I have fatal error on **setUseObjects**. Error is `Fatal error: Call to undefined method Google_Client::setUseObjects()`. I have done some authorization on my google analytics backend also.

Please let me know the whole process for getting report on my server. Because I am not able to understand the developers guide of google analytics which they have given.

---

Comment: Don't use real values for code sample(client secret, developer key etc..). According to your error you are not using latest client library. There are some changes recently as it is still in beta. Please update it from https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client

Comment: @ShanthaKumara I have taken the code form github itself.

Comment: make sure you arnt missing any of the files in the google dir. and double check the path is corect.

Comment: @deepakbhardwaj, I'm using version "1.0.4-beta" and there is no method that fits to your sample code. You might be using older version of Google API client library.

Answer (score 10):

The problem you are having is that you have the wrong client lib.   The Hello Analytics API tutorial was created using the old lib on [Code.google - google-api-php-client](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/source/browse/#svn/trunk/src%253Fstate%253Dclosed)   Not the newer version on [github](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client).

Update:
Because of the fact that the tutorial still hasn't been updated I have made a tutorial that may help.  [Google Oauth2 php](http://goo.gl/daGiPO).  The code below is ripped directly from it.  The tutorial will be kept up to date you may want to check that for any changes.

```
<?php         
require_once 'Google/Client.php';     
require_once 'Google/Service/Analytics.php';       
session_start();      
$client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName("Client_Library_Examples");
    $client->setDeveloperKey("{devkey}");  
    $client->setClientId('{clientid}.apps.googleusercontent.com');
    $client->setClientSecret('{clientsecret}');
    $client->setRedirectUri('http://www.daimto.com/Tutorials/PHP/Oauth2.php');
    $client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'));

    //For loging out.
    if ($_GET['logout'] == "1") {
    unset($_SESSION['token']);
       }   

    // Step 2: The user accepted your access now you need to exchange it.
    if (isset($_GET['code'])) {

        $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);  
        $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
        $redirect = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
        header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
    }

    // Step 1:  The user has not authenticated we give them a link to login    
    if (!$client->getAccessToken() && !isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
        $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
        print "<a class='login' href='$authUrl'>Connect Me!</a>";
        }        

    // Step 3: We have access we can now create our service
    if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
        print "<a class='logout' href='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?logout=1'>LogOut</a><br>";
        $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
        $service = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);    

        // request user accounts
        $accounts = $service->management_accountSummaries->listManagementAccountSummaries();

       foreach ($accounts->getItems() as $item) {
        echo "Account: ",$item['name'], "  " , $item['id'], "<br /> \n";        
        foreach($item->getWebProperties() as $wp) {
            echo '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;WebProperty: ' ,$wp['name'], "  " , $wp['id'], "<br /> \n";    

            $views = $wp->getProfiles();
            if (!is_null($views)) {
                foreach($wp->getProfiles() as $view) {
                //  echo '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;View: ' ,$view['name'], "  " , $view['id'], "<br /> \n";    
                }
            }
        }
    } // closes account summaries

    }
 print "<br><br><br>";
 print "Access from google: " . $_SESSION['token']; 
?>
```

Comment: So which lib should I use?

Comment: I would use the new one. There are some samples with it. Side Note:The GA devs of the problem with that tutorial. They are working on new ones. But I cant tell you when they will be live.

Comment: 7 months later and the old tutorial is still there and the code still generates this error on fresh install from GitHub.  Lame

Comment: @jerrygarciuh yes i know, I have a tutorial that should help http://www.daimto.com/google-oauth2-php/

Comment: Thanks @DaImTo I managed to get it working by reading several SO posts.  I'll take a look at the link too.  Appreciate it!

Comment: Thanks so much. As of December 2, 2014 I can confirm this is working!

Comment: So, what is the equivalent of `setUseObjects` function?