# Can I let some user to see my analytics data?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I made a website for a friend and I registered this site under my google analytics account. Now I want to use the `google-analytics-api-php` to create a private page in which I and my friend can see the statistics of the website.

I followed the instructions of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22404387/2410157) answer and I got that example working. Only at the end I realised that this is not what I though. If I understand correctly that example let an user authorize the webpage to access HIS analytics data while I need to authorize whoever enters the page to see the data of MY analytics account.

Is it possible? How?

Comment: why don't you just add him as a user in Google Analytics? https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1009702?hl=en

Comment: @cmorrissey Because he is an old men with low experience of PCs. Also if I make some simple view for him in google analytics I think that the overall interface is too much for him.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is sufficient to add a new user to the GA account. In this way not only the new user will see the site data in his GA account but he can also login in a page that uses the **GA php API** giving in this way the permission at the page to use his data.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a new user to your GA account with limited permissions (Read & Analyze), as shown below:

[image]

Comment: If I add him in my google analytics account when he logged in the page I create with the google-analytics-api-php can he see the data?

Comment: He'll see the same reporting view that you would, but the only difference is that he won't be able to edit anything. You can try for yourself by giving access to an alternate account with read-only access, and then log in to your GA with that read-only account.

Comment: I didn't mean in google analytics. I would like to know if adding the user in GA has some effect also in my php example code